# Data structure library vendors

Tags: c++, c

Is there any Data Structure library with License available. Are there any vendors who sell their Data structure library .My need is, not to go with Open Source.

Adding more details:
I need a data structure library in C , so that I can use it on Windows as well as on RTOS. Also I need a stable data structure library with vendor support.

If you know any vendor who sells the data structure library / Any one of you who had buyed data structure library , kindly provide me the details

Comment: Certainly depends on what kind of data structures you need. Besides what is available in the standard C++ library, what do you need ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your needs? What kind of data structure you need that is not in stdlib yet?

Comment: In addition, does "not to go with OpenSource" include being unable to use dual-licensed libraries ?

Comment: And by 'not open source' do you really mean 'with vendor support'?

Comment: They might mean 'not GPL,' since the license is commercially unfriendly and one of the most well known, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The [boost](http://www.boost.org/) C++ libraries provide a wide variety of data structures and other functions. They are "open source", but very liberally licensed: you can produce commercial software with them, for example.

If you require it, you can pay for [commercial support](http://www.boostpro.com/) for the boost libraries, too.

Answer (score 2):

[Dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com/) sells its implementation of the C++ Standard Library. But most C++ compilers include an implementation the Standard Library at no extra cost. This already contains many common data structures